# Is it fair to say that set theory is meta–mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

Is it fair to say that set theory is meta–mathematics?

(Understanding Set Theory (definition))

Instead of distinguishing the properties of one 'thing' ... a number or numerical proxy such as "x" ... we're talking about properties of ALL things and in this way, a more 'pure' or 'core' symbolic representation of reality?

Comment: Even if set theory discusses more 'universal' concepts I don't think it qualifies as meta-mathematics per se. To me, the example of a meta-mathematical theory would be mathematical logic, as it aims to describe mathematical reasoning.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Clear explanation.

Comment: Mathematical theories are not just about numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not the way we normally intend it.**

[Metamathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics) comprises metatheories, studying mathematics with mathematical methods. To me, that means [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) or something like it. Set theory is just another of the branches of mathematics that might be thereby studied. But it's an understandable question, because you're likely to run into metamathematics alongside a discussion of set theory.

For example, if you're reading about $\mathsf{ZFC}$, the author might talk about proper classes, and in doing so they're really telling you what we learn in a metatheory, and talk about in a metalanguage of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The reason this happens is simply that it's very convenient at times to talk about "the class of all sets meeting this condition, whether or not there is a set with exactly those sets as elements, but if there is we'll say said class 'is' that set, by which we really mean they have the same elements".

Or at the easier end of the scale, let's say we were just talking about numbers, when all of a sudden *sets* of numbers get mentioned. These "bunch together" numbers in the same way classes bunch together sets, in that you can have a first-order theory talking about one kind of object, only for a metatheory to let us aggregate them. You might say that's an exercise in a metatheory, but it's a theory that practice has made part of "mainstream" enough mathematics to make the prefix *meta-* feel inappropriate here.

Sets are not a "special" enough way of "going up a level" to capture what *meta-* usually means. Ultimately, "metamathematics" is a term we use when we want to say things like, "this statement is undecidable in this theory because the latter meets certain criteria we can only talk about once you've learned enough metatheoretical jargon to follow a discussion *of* theories, rather than of more ordinary mathematical objects *in* a theory."

Comment: Ok, thank you. Clear explanation.

Comment: Given that there are plenty of results in multiple fields of mathematics (especially algebra and number theory) that can be proved using model theory, I'm not sure it's fair to call model theory Metamathematics either.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Fair point. One might say those are examples of model theory bleeding into and becoming useful in ordinary mathematics, so only the rest of model theory can be meta, and perhaps not even that.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say so. It is precisely the essence of mathematics to make statements of about all objects satisfying some property. For example, a typical theorem is:

Let $V$ be a vector space. Then $V$ has a basis.

or in other words:

For all objects $V$ that are vector spaces, it is true that $V$ has a basis.

However, it is reasonable to say that mathematics is the study of (more or less) [formal theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) - Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory is one of those. With this in mind, there are ways of considering the properties of theories themselves and make statements about classes of theories. Such are called [meta-theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatheory) and are probably closer to what you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Clear explanation.